# Transform LINQ skip and take into custom paging logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, rest

I am using ASP.NET Web API to create a RESTful API.
A typical controller is requesting entities from my repository using LINQ to objects. My repository is not using Entity Framework and does not access any database. Instead, it uses external RESTFul services for data access. 
The controller uses Skip() and Take() to implement paging.

The part I would like to understand is whether it makes sense to transform Skip() and Take() into request parameters when calling the external web services. In other words: I am interested to find out whether Skip() and Take() of LINQ can be used to apply paging for the call to the external web service instead of applying paging on the resulting IEnumerable containing all objects.

This is a typical LINQ statement to retrieve data from my own repository.

```
var userRoles = from userRole in Repository.UserRole.Load()
                            .Skip(10)
                            .Take (10)
                            select ModelFactory.Create(userRole);
```

My repository will request the data from the external web service like this:

```
protected override IEnumerable<UserRole> LoadAll()
{
    //....
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(GetUrl());
    string parameters = 
             String.Format("?sessionkey={0}&take={1}&skip={2}", take, skip, Session);
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(parameters).Result;
    //....skipped. deseralize response using JsonConvert and return IEnumerable<UserRole>
}
```

Is it possible and reasonable to make use of the LINQ query and translate it into the take and skip parameters of the web request or should I pass plain old skip & take integer parameters to the LoadAll() method?

Comment: Better if you pass Take and Skip to the remote service, thus avoiding to download all the records to then take only some of them.

Comment: Agreed, definitely passing the paging parameters to the remote service is what's best. 
My question though is how, in the LoadAll() method, I can find out what values take and skip have. Can I somehow grab them from the LINQ query? If not, then I will pass in parameters instead of using LINQ for Take and Skip. However, that would mean in my controller I am using LINQ for paging (or not) because I have to know how my repository does paging. That seems unclean to me.

Comment: Is `Load()` another name for `LoadAll()` here? Is your first code snippet calling the method in your second code snippet?

Comment: My apologies for not having explained this. LoadAll() will be called by Load(). Load() is the public interface, LoadAll() is protected.

Comment: @DavidHartmann, IMHO the @JLRische answer is what you`re looking for. Considering that is the remote service that has direct access to the data, the Reposity classes should try very hard to pass filtering parameters to the remote service (Where, Take, Skip, etc.). That is, filtering on the client side should be the exception, not the rule. Finally, the remote service should abstract the parameters using more generic names, like ``page``, ``pageSize``, and other parameters that will be applied using Where() expressions.

Comment: I agree to the solution proposed by @JLRishe. It's straight forward to pass the paging parameters. 
Applying the paging to the remote service is obvious. The scenario I had in mind was this:
Suppose my concrete repository implementation will change to entity framework. Suddenly, the Take() and Skip() will be applied on the database server. Now, the paging parameters become obsolete, or at least redundant. So LINQ is translated to SQL, and I was evaluating doing that for the web request as well. I tried to find out whether a decoupled design is worth the pain. Looks like it's not.

Comment: @DavidHartmann Switching to entity framework wouldn't necessarily make the paging parameters obsolete. All you'd have to do is perform your EF query _within_ `LoadAll()` and you can translate the paging parameters into `Take` and `Skip` on the EF query. The interface of `LoadAll()` doesn't necessarily have to change in that case.

Comment: @JLRishe That's a great point, I hadn't looked at this that way before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the `take` and `skip` values into your `LoadAll()` method (or my preference would be to use `page` and `pageSize` values and translate them into `take` and `skip`).

While it's most likely possible to come up with some LINQ provider that allows extracting the `Take` and `Skip` used and somehow route them through your system, this would be far too complicated compared to any benefit it could provide.

If you're concerned that having explicit `take` and `skip` parameters exposes an implementation detail of your repository, that's all the more reason to use `page` and `pageSize`, and translate these into `take` and `skip` behind the scenes. I'd say that this would expose nothing about how your repository does paging.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.
I checked the web for creating LINQ providers, and Microsoft is giving an example for a similar scenario here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb546158(v=vs.110).aspx.
That indeed looks too complicated.